# Does System.out.println violate the law of demeter?

Tags: java, law-of-demeter

Does `System.out.println` violate the law of demeter?

If not, why?

Comment: In a design view or in a code view?

Comment: well since demeter is a reglementation of organic farming in germany, i'd say no, because its nothing to do with it ;)

Comment: Was my first thought too, Joe, but since SO is not about farming.. :-)

Comment: I bet it does, System.out.println violates alot of laws, but the law of logic is hurted the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on view.

LoD: Yes, because it uses the console. Under LoD you can't assume access.

LoD-F: Yes, because it uses more than one dot. The LoD-F states that in any method usage only the object may know the internal structure of itself.
IE

```
System.out.println()
```

requires knowledge of the structure of system (that it has .out) to reach println(),

For System to not break LoD-F it would have to be

```
System.println()
```

To break the formal rules down with example, println() (the method) may only access:

1. system itself
2. println()'s parameters
3. any objects created/instantiated within println()
4. system's direct component objects
5. a global variable, accessible by system, in the scope of println()

(I know, it's a reversed reference here as the code should be the method calling it, but it actually swings both ways.)

Answer (score 1):

`System.out` is actually a "global state", and yes, technically it violates the "law of demeter". But:

- you should avoid using `System.out.println(..)`. Use a logger (log4j, logback, slf4j) instead.
- you are not supposed to rely (and test) anything that's for the purpose of logging to a console. (this does not concern complex logging systems that later aggregate the logged information)

Comment: Ideally you should use Aspects, and completely hide the logger (a cross-cutting concern) from your source base altogether. This allows you to swap loggers as needed (as speed, memory, and other requirements are prone to change).

Comment: well, not always. You can log common information, like what's invoked, with what params, execution times, etc. But you can't log intermediate debug messages.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`System.out` is a global variable.

> More formally, the Law of Demeter for functions requires that a method
>   m of an object O may only invoke the methods of the following kinds of
>   objects:[2]
>
> 1. O itself
> 2. m's parameters
> 3. Any objects created/instantiated within m
> 4. O's direct component objects
> 5. A global variable, accessible by O, in the scope of m **<- This one**

-- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

By the 5th rule, you can invoke any method of the global variable `System.out` from within any context.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say not really, since it calls `Object.toString()` and doesn't tightly couple with any class in any way; it just tells the object to convert itself to a string.

---

Edit:

If you mean the call itself, rather than what happens in the call, then I'd say yes it does, because it tightly couples your program to the `System.out` field.

Comment: He's most likely meaning the call itself.

Comment: he means the call to System.out.println() method, not the implementation of the method :-)

Answer (score 0):

It breaks the law, since it uses "more than one dot", and exposes the fact that it is using another object for the println call.